# Is Brother Eye sinister?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

Reading O.M.A.C #1 (Sept 2011) and it seems that the satellite known as Brother Eye is controlling O.M.A.C. to gain access to some computer system.

He's not concerned with the safety of any innocents in the way, and he's not concerned with the safety of the guy who was transformed as O.M.A.C.

Is this satellite sentient? Is he evil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Brother Eye**

There has simply not been enough exposure to this current DCU 52 version of Brother Eye to be able to make a guess as to what its current motivations might be. In its previous iterations, it was a worldwide covert monitoring system and its ethical engine might have been considered questionable.

With the newest release, it could return to a more altruistic engine as it was originally conceived of, or remain the morally bereft AI of the previous DCU.

Judging from its overall lack of concern for citizens, or collateral damage, or its OMAC subject, it appears we can assume Brother Eye does not currently seem to be a beneficial AI and has its own agenda.

I suspect the current behavior of Brother Eye is designed to create tension between OMAC and Brother Eye as a plot device.